# Defi Launchpad Website

Tags: solidity, web3js, web3.py

Hello every body hope all are good ?

I'm seaching some website where i can find launchpad protocol for new token on different chain ?

I know only know :
Pinksale
Uniscrypt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Binance Smart Chain:`

BakerySwap Launchpad (https://www.bakeryswap.org)

BSCPad (https://bscpad.com)

`Ethereum:`

NFT Launch (https://nftlaunch.com)

Polkastarter (https://www.polkastarter.com)

DuckSTARTER (https://duckstarter.io)

`Polygon:`

Polycat Finance (https://polycat.finance)

Polkastarter (https://www.polkastarter.com) - supports both Ethereum and Polkadot

`Solana:`

SolStarter (https://solstarter.org)

Solanium (https://solanium.io)

`Cardano:`

CardStarter (https://cardstarter.io)

OccamFi (https://occam.fi)

`Avalanche:`

Avalaunch (https://avalaunch.app)

`Polkadot:`

Astar Network (formerly Plasm) (https://astar.network)

Polkastarter (https://www.polkastarter.com) - supports both Ethereum and Polkadot

`Fantom`:

SpookySwap (https://spookyswap.finance)

FTMStarter (https://ftmstarter.io)